Obtaining the covariance matrix of a uniform distribution over a section of a unit sphere
My problem looks simple
Let $X$ be uniformly distributed with the constraints
$$X \cdot v_1 > 0$$
$$X \cdot v_2 > 0$$
Where $X, v_1, v_2$ are all unit vectors of $d$ dimensions.
I want the covariance matrix over this distribution.
In other words, i want a way to calculate the covariance matrix of a uniform distribution over the area intersected by two half hyperspheres.
I realise there has to be an integral calculation of $XX^T$ over the intersected area. I also realise that it probably makes sense to move to polar coordinates.
But I can't get much from there.
Would appreciate any lead, resource or help on this!
